# How to show only 1 row on index

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I am using Arduino, ESP8266 to send data sensor to localhost. See image below, I don't know to to make at the index.php only show 1 latest data only on 1 row like the rectangle with red color in the image.

[image]

```
<?php

    include("dbcon.php");   

    $link=$cn;
    $i=0;
    $result=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM `node` where 1");

?>

<html>
   <head>
      <title>Sensor Data1</title>
      <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">  
   </head>
<body>
   <Center><h1>Sensor Readings</h1>

   <table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;No&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;Waktu / Tarikh&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;Temperature &nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;Humidity &nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;Length(CM)&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;Node&nbsp;</td>   
        </tr>


      <?php 
             while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                printf("<tr><td> &nbsp;%d </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td></tr>", 
                   ++$i, $row["tarikh"], $row["temperature"], $row["humidity"], $row["height"], $row["node"]);
             }      

      ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write ('<p>Waktu sekarang: <span id="date-time">', new Date().toLocaleString(), '<\/span>.<\/p>')
if (document.getElementById) onload = function () {
    setInterval ("document.getElementById ('date-time').firstChild.data = new Date().toLocaleString()", 50)
}
</script>
   </table></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the attached image it looks like you want to limit the output to a single **row**, not a single **column**. You could do this using a combination of the `order by` and `limit` clauses:

```
SELECT * FROM `node` ORDER BY `waktu` DESC LIMIT 1
```